# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'classes_taken' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.6, local-variables

I am completely new to learning python (this is my first CIS class).
I keep getting this error :UnboundLocalError: local variable 'classes_taken' referenced before assignment. Any help would be greatly appreciated as i try to wrap my head around all of the new information I'm learning.
Code included below:

```
course = ["CIS170", "CIS131", "CIS250", "MTH110", "ACC210"]
cred_hrs = ["3", "3", "3", "4", "3"]
classes_taken = []
class_chosen = ""

print("Welcome to registration!")

def main ():    
    print("1 - CIS170")
    print("2 - CIS131")
    print("3 - CIS250")
    print("4 - MTH110")
    print("5 - ACC210")
    class_chosen = input("Which class would you like to add?")
    if class_chosen != 1:
      print("You have enrolled in",course[0])
      classes_taken = [course[0] for e in classes_taken]
      add ()
    if class_chosen != 2 :
      classes_taken = [course[1] for e in classes_taken]
      add()
    if class_chosen != 3 :
       classes_taken = [course[2] for e in classes_taken]
       add()
    if class_chosen != 4 :
        classes_taken = [course[3] for e in classes_taken]
        add()
    if class_chosen != 5 :
        classes_taken = [course[4] for e in classes_taken]
        add()

    def add ():
    more= input("Would you like to add more classes? Press Y or N")
    if more == "y" or more == "Y":
        main()
    if more == "n" or more == "N":
        displayorder ()

    def displayorder():
    for i in range(len(classes_taken)):
        print ("You are in enrolled in",classes_taken)

main()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\owner\Documents\Registration.py", line 47, in <module>
    main ()
  File "C:\Users\owner\Documents\Registration.py", line 21, in main
    classes_taken = [course[0] for e in classes_taken]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'classes_taken' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: please read [ask], review the [tour] and improve your indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to create a new local 'classes_taken' variable inside the main function. You have two option:

1. Either you can change the name of the variable to which the value is being assigned to or
2. You can use 'global' keyword.

You classes_taken variable is outside the main function. You can use global keyword to access the classes_taken variable inside the main function as follows:

```
def main():
    global classes_taken
    print("1 - CIS170")
    # ....
    # Your code
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Sorry if it was a silly question. One other question, at the end, in the add () module it keeps asking the question whether i enter y or n? Am i missing something simple here?

Comment: For your current code, it will accept 'n' or 'N' 4 times before exiting because you have used 5 'if' loops (one of them won't execute if the number entered is between 1 to 5) and each of them is calling add() function. You can use if/elif/else loop to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
classes_taken = [course[0] for e in classes_taken]
```

The variable `classes_taken` on the right has not been assigned a value yet, therefore, the whole expression on the right cannot be calculated.

But before that, you have a problem in your algorithm. You should review that problem first. If you don't know what's wrong, tell us what you're trying to do by using which variables to represent what.

Comment: I am trying to make a new array by pulling my elements from the "course" list with the users input which is what I was hoping to achieve from the classes_taken empy array at the top. Basically asking the user which classes they want to enroll in, saving those classes to a new array, and printing that array back to them after they've chosen all of their classes and how many credit hours they are taking. All of which the credit hours are 3 other than MTH110.

Comment: Looking at this comment and that you're being asked yes or no multiple time, I would suggest changing the `if` blocks into: `if classes_chosen == "1"` new line, tab `classes_taken = classes_taken +  [course[0]] `. Same with other `if` blocks.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your help! It's all still really foreign to me but I'm glad they have groups like this for everyone to learn and share knowledge!